# Is it a [question] or a [challenge]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-wikis

Both of these tags are active on Meta: [challenges](/questions/tagged/challenges) and [questions](/questions/tagged/questions)

One has 17 questions, the other 44. One has no tag wiki, the other does. They both, more or less, ask about questions on the main site. There is, currently, [no overlap in tagging](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/questions+challenges).

Additionally, we have 6 tags ([asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions), [closed-questions](/questions/tagged/closed-questions), [deleted-questions](/questions/tagged/deleted-questions), [protected-questions](/questions/tagged/protected-questions), [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question), [unanswered-questions](/questions/tagged/unanswered-questions)) about *questions* and 2 ([challenge-quality](/questions/tagged/challenge-quality), [weekly-challenges](/questions/tagged/weekly-challenges)) about *challenges*. [Relevant meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9439/66833)

What should be done about these tags? I see 3 options:

- Synonymise/merge one with another
- Clearly distinguish the difference between the two, including editing the tag wikis to detail these differences
- Something else?

Comment: I think [tag:questions] is better, because it includes things like [tag:tips] that [tag:challenges] doesn't.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms That said, I think both have their own uses. [tag:challenges] is specifically for challenges; [tag:questions] is for everything that is asked on main.

Answer (score 4):

### Merge + synonymize challenges into questions, keep the sub-tags

I've taken a look at all of the [challenges](/questions/tagged/challenges) questions, and in my opinion all of them a) could or even *should* be put under [questions](/questions/tagged/questions) because they apply to all questions (including things like [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips)), not just challenges; or b) are classified more precisely by another tag and so the distinction doesn't matter much (e.g. [this question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14554/can-i-redo-the-solve-rubiks-cube-challenge) is more about [reposting](/questions/tagged/reposting), and the distinction between whether it's a [challenge](/questions/tagged/challenge) or not hardly matters).

(Also, like [Redwolf said](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22440/is-it-a-question-or-a-challenge/22441#comment74229_22440), questions is a better tag if we combine them because it includes things like [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) that aren't challenges)

However, the sub-tags make sense - asking questions is about general questions, closing, deleting, protecting, and unanswered all apply to questions in general, and specific-question should support all questions, not just challenges. On the other hand, quality standards for challenges are unique from not only other questions (like [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips)) on CGCC but on nearly the entire network (probably excluding Puzzling). Similarly, "weekly tips" doesn't make sense; that one only really applies to challenges.

So my proposed/recommended course of action is such:

- synonymize and merge [challenges](/questions/tagged/challenges) into [questions](/questions/tagged/questions)
- do not change any of the remaining 8 tags